# Is there a way I can replace a period before the number by adding it right after it?

Tags: replace, ms-word

[image: Single number followed by a period (1.)] is to be converted to [image: Period followed by a single number (1.)]. Sometimes, there may be two or more numbers with a comma in between the numbers. For example, [image: Multiple numbers followed by a period (1,2.)] is to be converted to [image: Period followed by two or more numbers (1,2.)]. I am using MS Word for this manuscript and found out that I need to make this change uniformly throughout. Also, the numbers used are superscript throughout. Is there any way I can do a Find and Replace to make this job quicker? Using Regex in replacing, probably?

Comment: How about this `^([\d,]+).$` then you can use the matched group and replace, something like `.$1`

Comment: You don't need RegEx - or any code at all for what you've described. A *wildcard* Find/Replace is all you need. In any event, Regex will destroy the formatting.

Comment: @macropod Could you expatiate how I could use a wildcard here? I looked around but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the required superscripting is in place, you could use a *wildcard* Find/Replace with:

```
Find = ([0-9,]{1,})(.)
Replace = \2\1
```

No code required.

Comment: This does not identify the characters that are in superscript, which I have to change.

Comment: Edit: I selected the superscript from the font in advanced search, however it still does not detect the text.

Comment: My apologies - I had the Find expression the wrong way around. Try it now. You do not need to specify the superscript attribute; indeed, doing so will prevent the F/R working.